# A request to receive data was disallowed, when creating a socket connection

Tags: python

I'm making a simple socket connection between server and client, when I want to receive data from the client, and write the data to a text file on the server Destkop, I'm getting an error on line **17** (`data = sock.recv(1024)`).

**Error:**

```
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.
```

**Server:**

```
import socket
import os
import random

randomName = str(random.randint(100, 1001)) + 'data.txt'
FilePath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop', randomName)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind((socket.gethostname(), 9889))
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print(f'{addr} has connected to the server.')
    with open(FilePath, 'wb') as f:
        if not f.writable():
            pass
        else:
            data = sock.recv(1024)
            f.write(data)
            exit(0)
```

**Client:**

I'm trying to send my computer host name and key ( key is just a string )

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9889))
        fromServer = sock.recv(1024)
        try:
            sock.send(socket.gethostname() + key)
        except:
            print('Cant send hostname and key')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code makes a socket object, and binds it to an address at port 9889 as a socket server. When clients connect to this address with a socket connection, the server listens for data, and stores it in the “data” variable.

For receiving data, you should use the connection that was made and not the socket. Therefore:

```
data = sock.recv(1024)
```

You should replace `sock` with `conn`

Comment: How can I send with connection in the client side ?

Comment: You right, I have been mistaken, you should send with the socket and receive the data in the connection. I updated my answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: Maybe this would help too: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Comment: But how can I recv with connection the data in the client side ?

Comment: At the client, send and receive with `socket`. Since the server is the one who listens and waits for a connection - you should use the connection for sending and receiving (at the server only)

Comment: No matter it is now working, but the file is empty when I try to write my host name and the key into the file. The file is empty.

Comment: Do you receiving the hostname and the key correctly?

Comment: There is no error when I'm sending the hostname and the key, but the file is empty.

Comment: Please add to your question this information and print the data that you receiving before writing it to the file. It seems like a different question, search about writing to file at google too, it might help.

Comment: No matter, I fixed it. תודה עמית